# Changing the resistance of a circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I am wondering, when we change the resistance in a circuit, does the voltage tend to increase or the ampere decrease? More specifically, under what conditions does what happen?

E.g. If we have a high-resistance voltmeter, does increasing the resistance of the circuit itself necessary increase the reading, or might the current just decrease further?

Comment: If you are going to measure a resistance in the voltmeter range, e.g. 0.1 Ω to 50 MΩ, then the maximum error you get depends on the voltmeter accuracy, typically 1 or 1.5 % for an industrial voltmeter. This is achieved with a voltmeter's very high internal resistance, much higher than the 50 MΩ of the example.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the resistance of a circuit does not necessarily increase the reading on your voltmeter. It depends on whether you use a voltage source or a current source.

E.g.: You circuit is powered by a 1.5V battery you will read 1.5 Volts when measuring on the ends of the circuit even if you increase the resistance.
But if you measure the current it will automatically decrease when increasing the resistance.

If you have a current source things are the other way around. Let's assume you're measuring 1.5V on your circuit. If you increase the resistance now the current stays constant which forces the voltage provided by the source to increase - you'll read a higher voltage.

In conclusion: Determine whether your source provides a constant voltage or a constant current - afterwards $U=RI$ will do the rest. :)

(Btw.: Batteries e.g. provide a more or less constant voltage)

I hoped that this answer fits for you.

All the best!